# Fetching from database, as JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to fetch data from my database, but when I visit `MYWEBPAGE.com/service.php?id=2` (yes, there is an article with that id), then it just writes:
`[true]`, instead for showing me the objects as json.

Here is my code:

```js
<?php
 

include('includingThis.php');

$idFromUrl = addslashes($_GET[id]);

$resultArray = array();
$tempArray = array();
 
if ($stmtTitle = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM artikler WHERE id=?")) {
 
 
    
    /* bind parameters for markers */
       $stmtTitle->bind_param("i", $idFromUrl);
    
    $stmtTitle->execute();
     
    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $stmtTitle->fetch()) {
      
  // Add each row into our results array
  $tempArray = $row;
     array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
 }
 
 // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
 echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
 
// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: BTW, you dont need this: `$idFromUrl = addslashes($_GET[id]);` if you are preparing. So remove the `addslashes` action.

Comment: And the reason you see `true`, is `$row = $stmtTitle->fetch()` is not how you use `fetch`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: This question could really be narrowed down into "I get {this} from my database, and when I run it through `json_encode`, it shows `true`." No need for the excess, and please include the actual results you're trying to run through `json_encode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble you had is with using `fetch`. It does not return a row, it returns a boolean. If you wish to get a row of * fields from a prepared statement (using `mysqli`), you can do it one of two ways.

1) If you have `mysqlnd` available:

You utilize `get_result` first, then `fetch_assoc`:

```
<?php
include('includingThis.php');
$resultArray = array();
if ($stmtTitle = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM artikler WHERE id=?")) {
    $stmtTitle->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);// just put your GET var here
    $stmtTitle->execute();
    $stmtTitle_result = $stmtTitle->get_result();// get the result object
    while($row = $stmtTitle_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultArray[] = $row;// add each row into resultArray directly
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
?>
```

2) If you do NOT have `mysqlnd` available:

You utilize `bind_result` but must know every field you need: (change fieldnames to what YOUR field names are, not my examples of `field` and `field2`)

```
<?php
include('includingThis.php');
$resultArray = array();
if ($stmtTitle = $con->prepare("SELECT field1,field2 FROM artikler WHERE id=?")) {
    $stmtTitle->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);// just put your GET var here
    $stmtTitle->execute();
    $stmtTitle->bind_result($field1,$field2);// bind to each field
    while($stmtTitle->fetch()) {
        $resultArray[] = array('field1'=>$field1,'field2'=>$field2);// add each field
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
?>
```

Incidentally, this is a bit easier (cleaner) using the PDO library.

Comment: This just leaves a blank page :/

Comment: $con is what is inside `includingThis.php`. Hate to say it, but it does still produce a blank page :(

Comment: Sorry for the trouble :D

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you might not have mysql native driver installed on your server to use get_result(),try with bind_result()

```
<?php


include('includingThis.php');
$resultArray = array();
if ($stmtTitle = $con->prepare("SELECT value1,value2 FROM artikler WHERE id=?")) {
    $stmtTitle->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);// just put your GET var here
    $stmtTitle->execute();
    $stmtTitle->store_result();
$stmtTitle->bind_result($value1,$value2);

    while($stmtTitle_result->fetch()) {
   $resultArray->val1=$value1;
  $resultArray->val12=$value2;


    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
?>
```